# Shell_NotifyIcon without sound in Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I show a notification with `Shell_NotifyIcon` without any sound on Windows 10?
I use `Shell_NotifyIcon` to show notifications nearby my program icon on the Windows tray. If the balloon notification appears, I hear a notification sound.

How to show a balloon notification without a sound?

BTW: I hear a sound on Windows 10, but there is no sound on Windows 7. Maybe this depends on my Windows 7 settings.

Comment: Don't overreact because the cheese was moved, this should be a user preference.  Even though [it is a bit clunky](http://www.howtogeek.com/219703/how-to-disable-notification-sounds-in-windows-10/) to configure.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I'll grant that this is a lousy question, and that there is little evidence of Codr having read the documentation. But honestly, I see names of several high-rep users in the close-voter list. There is nothing "unclear about what you're asking" about this question. If you don't understand what is being asked, you don't know enough to vote to close. Don't abuse "unclear" as "no research effort", that's the downvote arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NIIF_NOSOUND (0x00000010)
>
> 0x00000010. Windows XP and later. Do not
> play the associated sound. Applies only to notifications.

Pass this as part of `dwInfoFlags` when constructing your [NOTIFYICONDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.

```
notifyData.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_NOSOUND | /*other flags*/
```